# R Row selection vector from data frame

Tags: r, subset

I want to implement a simple row selection vector using the 'country' column on the below **lat_all** data frame in R.

```
pop   country      lat
12.4  Afghanistan  62
24.3  Australia    12
4     New Zealand  10
100   Japan        30
12    Fiji         28
```

Using a selection below which I can change easily such as

```
selection <- c("Afghanistan","Australia","Japan")
```

I want the result to be:

```
        pop            country       lat
1      12.4        Afghanistan       62
2      24.3          Australia       12
4       100              Japan       30
```

Only way I can get what I want so far is using the below which doesn't use the selection vector

```
lat_all[ lat_all[2]==("Afghanistan") | lat_all[2]==("Australia") | lat_all[2]==("Japan"), ]
```

I don't understand why something like `lat_all[2]==selection` doesn't work for me. The selection vector only finds Afghanistan and Japan. Australia is FALSE and any output using that vector skips Australia.

Comment: `lat_all[ lat_all$country %in% selection, ]`

Comment: Thanks, I have not learnt the %in% match function. This helps. Could you or anyone please point out what I'm missing and why my original     lat_all[2]==selection doesn't work?

Comment: `lat_all[2]==selection` is comparing 2 vectors to see if each value is equal to its corresponding value in the other vector. So it's comparing item 1 in `lat_all[1]` with item 1 in `selection` and so on... eg: `c(1,2) == c(2,1)` returns `FALSE FALSE`

Comment: as per @rosscova 's comment; the comparison you tried is testing `Afghanistan == Afghanistan`, then `Australia == Australia`, then `New Zealand == Japan`, then as `selection` is shorter than `lat_all`, it gets recycled, so the next comparison is `Japan == Afghanistan`, then `Fiji == Australia`

Comment: We require reproducible examples. Please provide your data in the form specified by the tag description.

Comment: Thanks SymbolixAU. That was an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use subset function

lat_all  <- subset(lat_all, country %in% selection)
```